# Can't connect to SQL in web.config

Tags: sql, asp.net

This is my web.config SQL:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="UsersDB"
      connectionString="Server=MYSQL5008.myWindowsHosting.com;Database=db_9b443f_users;Uid=9b443f_users;Pwd=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
                userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers> 
        <clear />
        <add
            name="SqlProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="UsersDB"
            applicationName="MyApplication"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
            requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong here please? Thanks!!
And don't mind the 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD', I just changed it so I can show you the code..

Comment: What's the error you get for connection failure?

Comment: That database name is puzzling. Are you certain that this is a Sql Server database and not a MySql one?

Comment: Nice catch @Steve. I am pretty sure it's a MySQL database.

Comment: They offer both, so it is possible. Also that `Uid` for the account name is typical of a MySql connectionstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your appear to be connecting to an external server

MYSQL5008.myWindowsHosting.com

ensure that there is an appropriate firewall rule in place to allow the SQL server connection through.  The default port is 1433.

There are quite a few other configuration items to check in general, but since this appears to be a hosted SQL solution the firewall is by far the most likely.

**UPDATE**

As noted by @Steve, is this a SQL Server or MySQL database?  If MySQL, you need to change the provider name in your configuration. See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html

for details.

Comment: This is MySQL. What do I need to change so it'd work?
I'm clicking 'ASP.NET Configuration' button in VS and this is the error I get after clicking 'Security':

Comment: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: Check out the appropriate MySQL docs for setting up the connection string http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html